# pandas and numpy: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, streamlit

Please help me solve this, I tried many solution but it doesn't work. In the Jupyter Notebook the Output I want are getting display but in Streamlit its getting error. I am newbie practicing ML.
`

```
    df = pd.read_csv("book1.csv")
    corrMatrix = df.corr(method='pearson')
    corrMatrix.head(17)


    def get_similar(question, rating):
        similar_ratings = corrMatrix[question] * (rating - 2.5)
        similar_ratings = similar_ratings.sort_values(ascending=False)
        return similar_ratings


    ratings = [(q1), (q2), (q3), (q4), (q5), (q6), (q7), (q8), (q9), (q10),
               (q11), (q12), (q13), (q14), (q15), (q16), (q17)]

    similar = pd.DataFrame()

    for question, rating in ratings:
         similar.append(get_similar(question, rating), ignore_index=True)

         similar.head(10)

         similars = similar.sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(3)

         df1 = pd.DataFrame(similar)

    st.write(df1)`
```

This is the Error I get.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\admin\desktop\thesissys\venv\lib\site- 
packages\streamlit\scriptrunner\script_runner.py", line 554, in _run_script
exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ThesisSys\venv\app.py", line 71, in <module>
show_predict()
File "C:\Users\admin\Desktop\ML\venv\predict_page.py", line 386, in show_predict
for question, rating in ratings:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: What are `q1`, `q2`...? I can reproduce the error if those are int. There should be two values to unpack, not a single value.

Comment: The q1,q2.. are the questions that are answered by the users(scale 1 to 5), the problems seems in the for loop question,rating in ratings. The dtype of all of this is float

Comment: `for question in range(len(ratings)):` and then use `ratings[question ]` instead of `rating`?

Comment: after reading your comment, I realize now the problem the ratings should have two variables. I fix the error now. Thank you for your comment.